# replace exact number in shell

Tags: shell, replace, sed, gsub

I have following matrix:

```
 0.380451   0.381955    0   0.237594
 0.317293   0.362406    0   0.320301
 0.261654   0.38797 0   0.350376
 0  0   0   1
 0  1   0   0
 0  0   0   1
 0  0.001504    0   0.998496
 0.270677   0.35188 0.018045    0.359398
 0.36391    0.305263    0   0.330827
 0.359398   0.291729    0.037594    0.311278
 0.359398   0.276692    0.061654    0.302256
```

And I want to replace only the zeros not the zeros followed by points to 0.001, how can I do that with sed or gsub?

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input plus what you have attempted so far, i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Please specify what you intend to replace the zeros _with_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Match whitespace in your replacement.

```
echo 0  0.001504    0   0.998496  | sed 's/0[\t ]/Z /g'
```

Comment: the only problem is it does not match the white space in the last column ..

Comment: you could match on an end of line or newline.

Comment: Won't this also replace `0` in `110`?

Comment: This has many issues, including various cases where it'll fail and non-portability. I'm very surprised the OP accepted it as it won't even produce the [presumably!] expected output from the posted sample input.

Answer (score 1):

This is not elegant, and not super portable, but it works on your specific example:

```
sed -e 's=^0 =X =g
        s= 0$= X=g 
        s= 0 = X =g' data.txt
```

First of all, it assumes that the fields in the input file are separated by one or more white spaces. The first part looks for "0" at the beginning of the line, the second at the end of the line, and the third finds "0" with spaces on both sides.

Any particular reason to use only sed for this? I am sure that a simple `awk` script could do a better job, and also be more robust.